# Cascode Current Mirror, Minimum output voltage

Tags: cmos, nmos, pmos, current-mirror, cascode

I can say that I understand simple current mirrors fairly well, but what i do not understant is the minimum output voltage requierd for the circuit to work properly...for the transistors to be in saturation.

[image: NMOS cascode current mirror]

**Vout**=V(D4).
**Vds_sat** is the saturation voltage of the transistor M2 and M4.
**Vt** is the treshold voltage.

**Why is the minimum output voltage, on the drain of the M4, equal to the Vout_min=Vt+2*Vds_sat, why not only 2*Vds_sat?**

From my perspective, separating the "output" and gorund (Vss=0V), there are only two transistors, both of whitch have a voltage drop of Vds_sat. Where does the Vt come from.

There is a second problem.

[image: PMOS cascode current mirror]

Vout=V(D4)

**What is the formula for the minimum output voltage of a PMOS cascode current mirror? Is it just Vout_min=Vdd-(Vt+2*Vds_sat)?**

Again, why or why not the Vt?

Thank you!

Comment: I will add an answer to the 2nd (PMOS related) question to my answer, it is not a complex answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why is the minimum output voltage, on the drain of the Q4, equal to the Vout_min=Vt+2 Vds_sat, why not only 2 Vds_sat?*

You're partly right that one could also consider \$2 * V_{ds,sat}\$ but then the circuit will not work any better than a standard mirror without the cascode Q4.

Imagine that we do make the output as low as \$2 * V_{ds,sat}\$. What would happen with Q4 ?

I hope you agree that Q4's gate is at \$2 V_t + 2V_{ds,sat}\$. So that means that the gate of Q4 is at a much higher (at least \$2V_t\$) voltage than Q4's drain and source. So it would be very much in triode region and just act as a low ohmic resistor.

In that situation Q2 will (try to) determine the output current. It will have a \$V_{ds}\$ of just above \$V_{ds,sat}\$

If you would **ignore** the **output impedance** \$r_{ds}\$of Q2 (assume it is very high) then the output current of the cascoded mirror would be more or less constant for \$V_{out} = 2*V_{ds,sat}\$ and more.

However we should not ignore \$r_{ds}\$ because the reason for using a cascode is often to mitigate the effect that \$r_{ds}\$ has !

*So how does a cascode mitigate the effect that \$r_{ds}\$ has ?*

It does this by keeping the \$V_{ds}\$ of the transistor which determines the output current, here that is Q2, constant. Under optimum circumstances the \$V_{ds}\$ of Q2 is kept at: \$V_t + V_{ds,sat}\$  (this is the \$V_{gs}\$ of Q1).

So if \$V_{ds,Q2} > V_t + V_{ds,sat}\$ has to be true then you're violating that when we make \$V_{out} = 2*V_{ds,sat}\$ as that is a much smaller voltage so there will be no "voltage headroom" for Q2. And the cascode does not work properly anymore.

So \$V_{out} > V_t + 2*V_{ds,sat}\$ in order to make the cascode work properly which is the point of the circuit !

*What is the formula for the minimum output voltage of a PMOS cascode current mirror? Is it just Vout_min=Vdd-(Vt+2Vds_sat)?*

Since the circuit with the PMOS is in essence the same circuit only "upside down" the same formulas and reasoning applies.

Trouble is with PMOS (compared to NMOS) is the **sign** of the voltages. PMOS have a **negative** \$V_t\$. Also their \$V_gs\$ is negative. Since for example for a diode-switched MOS \$V_{ds,sat}\$ increases \$V_{gs}\$ so do not subtract \$V_{ds,sat}\$ ! Same as for an NMOS when \$V_t= -0.6 V\$ and \$V_{ds,sat} = -0.2 V\$ you have to add them so \$V_{gs}\$ becomes -0.8 V.

So indeed the **maximum** \$V_{out}\$ (note that here making \$V_{out}\$ lower will make the PMOS mirror happyer) will be \$Vdd - V_t - 2V_{ds,sat}\$

Comment: I can not thank you enough! You have saved me from a loads of trubble. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure ! Enjoy CMOS mirrors :-)